# How to call a function/change bool value in html django by script

Tags: python, jquery, django

I simply want to use 2 for loops in django template with 'if' in inside loop. For now It looks like this:

```
{% for i in tiles_numer %}
   {% for p in path %}
      {% if p == i %}
        <div class = "tile" style = "background-color: black;" value = "{{i}}">

        </div>
      {%endif %}
    {%endfor%}
 {%endfor%}
```

But i need something like(i will show u how it would looks like in regular python):

```
 for i in tiles_numer:
    check = False
    for p in path:
       if p == i 
          do_something()
          check = True
     if check == False:
         do_somethig_v2()
```

I have a problem with a bool part
My idea is to do this with hidden input, can you show me how to call a function (wrote in jquery) that will change value of input ( I would use it as a bool).
Or maybe there is a better way to do this?
I hope I expressed myself clearly :)

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are trying to do - but Django templates are supposed to be for *presentation* logic, not more complex logic like setting variables. You should generally do such things in your view rather than your template, and pass the template what it needs to render the desired output. In your case this may involve altering the `tiles_number` data structure to hold this Boolean info you need - but that may be wrong because, as I said, your intention isn't clear.

Comment: Ok, I did it with tuple. thanks